# Clarification on lists and removing elements

Tags: c++, list, stl, pointers, object

If I have a `list<object*>>* queue` and want to pop the first object in the list and hand it over to another part of the program, is it correct to use (sketchy code):

```
object* objPtr = queue->first();
queue->pop_first();
return objPtr;  // is this a pointer to a valid memory address now?
```

?

According to the documentation on http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/pop_front/ it calls the destructor of the deleted element, but I'm confused as to whether it means the linked list's node object, or the actually stored "user" object.

Edit: I might be `front` instead of `first`,  my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is a valid pointer. List will not release the memory allocated by you. List will destroy its internal not the user object.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's valid: Since you put **pointers** into the list, only the **pointer** gets destroyed, not the object itself.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes `objPtr` contains pointer to a valid memory.**

When you insert an element into a `std::list`, `list` makes a copy of it. In your case the element is an address (a pointer) so list makes a copy of the address and stores it.

```
object * optr = queue->pop_front();
```

optr now points to the object

```
queue->pop_front();
```

removes the element (an address/pointer) from the `list`, `optr` already points to your object.

After you're done with the object don't forget do delete it otherwise you end up with memory leak.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    static int count;

    A() : val(count++) { cout << "A(" << val << ")" << endl; }
    ~A()               { cout << "~A(" << val << ")" << endl; }

    int val;
};

int A::count = 0;

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, A& a) { return os << a.val; }

int main()
{
    list<A*> alist;

    for (unsigned int i = 3; i; --i) alist.push_back(new A());
    for (unsigned int i = 3; i; --i)
    {
        A * aptr = alist.front();
        alist.pop_front();
        cout << *aptr << endl;
        delete aptr;
        aptr = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard indeed says (23.2.2.3/5) that the destructor of the element's type is called.  But this type is a pointer here, and the destructor of a pointer does nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is well but it is better to use `list< boost::shared_ptr<object> >`.

```
   shared_ptr < object> objPtr = queue->first();
   queue->pop_first();
   return objPtr;
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but here's my opinion: You can't simply switch from native pointers to shared_ptr so this answer is not very useful.

Comment: Why is it better to use shared_ptr when you don't fully know the requirements.

Comment: Because if someone doesn't know whether the list, when deleting the contained pointers, will also delete the pointed to objects, then that someone is _very_ unlikely to get manual memory management wrong?

Comment: @mxp: 1) It's certainly trivial in the code given. 2) IME experience switching to smart pointers is mostly non-trivial where the code does dubious things with naked pointers. 3) Using naked pointers in containers is bound to create leaks.

Comment: I downvoted it. And the reasons given above were mine for downvoting. boost::shared_ptr is neither an answer to the question nor it is objectively "better" than raw pointers. There are some applications where you don't need shared_ptrs. If they were always "better" then C++ would be garbage collected by default. It isn't because they are not always "better". Just because putting naked pointers into containers is more difficult doesn't make shared_ptrs automatic. And still, the question is not being answered.

Comment: In fact, this answer could be worse since it does not tell the questioner that the signature to the function must change. What if the questioner sees the error "can't convert shared_ptr<object> to object*" and he just adds a & to ptr. Now the shared_ptr, will probably delete the object when it goes out of scope (the object is no longer in the list) and he's returning a bad ptr. shared_ptr is wonderful paradigm, but it does require changes to your whole system. Can't just put in some parts of the code and not in other parts.

Comment: @jmucchiello: There's an important differnece between smart pointers and GC: Destruction is still deterministic with smart pointers, while it kicks in non-deterministically with GC. I still believe that, for someone who doesn't know what happens to heap objects when a list deletes the pointers, smart pointers are the answer to their problem. I guess we just have to agree to disagree.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove the elements, STL containers will not destroy the user objects allocated on heap.

```
class A
{

};


list<A*> PointerToObjectList;

A* ptr = new A();
PointerToObjectList.push_back(ptr);
```

If you remove the ptr from the list, list will not delete the object automatically. You need to explicitly call delete once the object is no longer being used.